# why do I get "Kotlin.Unit" error and how to fix it?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(){
val cal = cals(15,3,"/")
    println(cal)
}

fun cals(num1:Int,num2:Int,operation:String){

     when (operation) {
        "+" -> num1 + num2
        "-" -> num1 - num2
        "*" -> num1 * num2
        "/" -> num1 / num2
        else -> 0
    }

}
```

This code above gives the "Kotlin.Unit" error why and how can I fix it? Thanks.

I tried something and it worked but I didn't understand it here is the code:

```
fun main(){
val cal = cals(15,3,"/")
    println(cal)
}

fun cals(num1:Int,num2:Int,operation:String):Int {

    return when (operation) {
        "+" -> num1 + num2
        "-" -> num1 - num2
        "*" -> num1 * num2
        "/" -> num1 / num2
        else -> 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin functions have to return a value, unlike say, methods in Java, where they can have a return type of `void`, which means they have no return value.

So how do you write functions that only has side effects? For example, what does `println` return? What does a Java `void` function return, from the Kotlin perspective? The answer us that their return type is `Unit`, and they return the value `Unit`. The type `Unit` only has one valid value - `Unit`.

By default, if you don't write a return type in a block-bodied function, like in your first code snippet, the return type is `Unit`, which is exactly why you see `kotlin.Unit` being printed.

Note that the `when` expression in the first code snippets contributes nothing to what the function returns. You are generally allowed to put random expressions as their own "statement" in function bodies. For example, this function compiles, but does nothing useful:

```
fun foo() {
    1
    Unit
    7 + 7
    "foo"
    null
    Math.E
}
```

So to fix this, you can specify a return type and `return` the value you want. This stops the Kotlin compiler from implicitly inserting a `return Unit` in there.

Alternatively, use an expression-bodied function:

```
fun cals(num1:Int,num2:Int,operation:String) =
     when (operation) {
        "+" -> num1 + num2
        "-" -> num1 - num2
        "*" -> num1 * num2
        "/" -> num1 / num2
        else -> 0
    }
```

The equal sign at the end of the first line indicates that it is an expression-bodied function, and this causes the compiler to try to infer the return type from the `when` expression you used.